# Unity (dependency injection): How to pass in a parameter to the constructor in RegisterType

Tags: c#, unity-container, ioc-container

Can anyone help?

I have a wpf app (shouldn't matter) and in the Onstart i have my bootstrap stuff.. Its like this..

```
        // Create unity container my service and repository
        container = new UnityContainer()
            .RegisterType<ISecurityRepository, SecurityRepository>()
            .RegisterType<ISecurityService, SecurityService>();
```

Basically ISecurityService expects me to pass in a ISecurityRepository, hence the above fails.

But i am little confused, do i have to create a new IsecurityRespository and then pass it in, this defeats the object doesn't it?

Is there anyway i say "pass into SecurityService the ISecurityRepository from the container", but it hasn't been built yet?

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the constructor definition of your service class?

Comment: Hi Lasse, I have added the information

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to create instances first. It all just works. That's the magic of IoC Containers.

Example:

```
public interface ISecurityService { }
public interface ISecurityRepository { }

public class SecurityService : ISecurityService
{
    public SecurityService(ISecurityRepository repository)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SecurityService created");
        Console.WriteLine("Repository is " + repository);
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "A SecurityService";
    }
}

public class SecurityRepository : ISecurityRepository
{
    public SecurityRepository()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("SecurityRepository created");
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "A SecurityRepository";
    }
}

public class MyClassThatNeedsSecurity
{
    public MyClassThatNeedsSecurity(ISecurityService security)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("My class has security: " + security);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (IUnityContainer container = new UnityContainer())
        {
            container.RegisterType<ISecurityRepository, SecurityRepository>()
                     .RegisterType<ISecurityService, SecurityService>();

            MyClassThatNeedsSecurity myClass =
                container.Resolve<MyClassThatNeedsSecurity>();
        }
    }
}
```

This will print:

```
SecurityRepository created
SecurityService created
Repository is A SecurityRepository
My class has security: A SecurityService
```

You have a number of options, such as pre-creating your instances (as you showed in your follow-up post) or extending the lifetime of injected dependencies so that they're not recreated every time they're needed. But for the base case, this will work.

Comment: Thans TrueWill! That worked, So see if i understand this correctly, Using registerTypes will create a new instance each time I do Resolve?  and using my way in my followup uses the same instance each time i use resolve?  So i suppose if need to keep an object alive its better to use RegisterInstance rather than registerType?

Comment: @mark: Yes, with the default RegisterType call a new instance will be created every time you call Resolve **and** the resolved type needs the dependency (directly or indirectly). Using RegisterInstance will give the same instance every time. You can also use the overloads to have Unity create the instance once and only once per container (like a Singleton); from the Unity help: "myContainer.RegisterType<IMyObject, MySingletonObject>(new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager());"

Comment: @TrueWill,what we should do if there are multiple constructors of service class ? Please see the below problem :-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23443921/how-to-register-service-class-with-multiple-repository-types-in-bootstrapper-fil?

Comment: @Pawan See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8853106/resolve-instance-with-multiple-constructors-using-unity

Answer (score 1):

here is some more information. The constructor of my class is

```
    public SecurityService(ISecurityRepository repository)
        : base(repository)
    {

    }
```

After playing around a little bit, i managed to do the following but this causes me to create instances FIRST ...  It seems to work.., but its an alternative.

```
        // Create unity container my service and repository
        ISecurityRepository securityRepository = new SecurityRepository();
        ISecurityService securityService = new SecurityService(securityRepository);

        container = new UnityContainer();
        container.RegisterInstance<ISecurityRepository>(securityRepository);
        container.RegisterInstance<ISecurityService>(securityService);
```

Comment: ,what we should do if there are multiple constructors of service class ? Please see the below problem :-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23443921/how-to-register-service-class-with-multiple-repository-types-in-bootstrapper-fil?noredirect=1#comment35940994_23443921