# How to register service class with multiple repository types in Bootstrapper file?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, unity-container, bootstrapper

There are 4 parameterized constructor of one of my service layer(ProductService).
And all of the 4 constructors are injected with different repository types.

```
public class ProductService : IProductService
{

   private IUserDal<Users> mUserDal { get; set; }
   private IItemDal<Item> mItemDal { get; set; }
   private IRoleDal<Role> mRoleDal { get; set; }
   private IBranchDal<Branch> mBranchDal { get; set; }

   public ProductService (IUserDal<Users> userDal)
   {
       mUserDal = userDal;
   }

   public ProductService (IItemDal<Item> itemDal)
   {
       mItemDal = itemDal;
   }

   public ProductService (IRoleDal<Role> roleDal)
   {
       mRoleDal = roleDal;
   }

   public ProductService (IBranchDal<Branch> branchDal)
   {
       mBranchDal = branchDal;
   }
}
```

> > And **ProductService** layer is use in some of the Controller classes.
> >
> > I am registering this ProductService class to Bootstrapper.cs(Unity DI) file with all of its dependencies types.But it's not registering properly.Some of the examples are below :-

**Type 1:**

```
   container.RegisterType<IUserDal<Users>, UserDal>();
   container.RegisterType<IItemDal<Item>,ItemDal>();
   container.RegisterType<IRoleDal<Role>,RoleDal>();
   container.RegisterType<IBranchDal<Branch>,BranchDal>();
   container.RegisterType<IProductService,ProductService>();
```

**Type 2:**

```
   container.RegisterType<IProductService, ProductService>(new InjectionConstructor(typeof(IUserDal<Users>), typeof(IItemDal<Item>), typeof(IRoleDal<Role>), typeof(IBranchDal<Branch>)));
```

> > But none of the above types are working.Can anyone know how to register any service class with multiple repository types in Bootstrapper file ?

Comment: Is it not an option to split this into four different services? To my eyes, that would make much more sense. Four small classes with super simple bootstrapping instead of one huge beast that possibly just becomes tricky to use because you have to think of what "type" of it you have to use.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how they are "not working"? Also, why do you have 4 different constructors like this? Won't `ProductService` need *all* of its dependencies?

Comment: @Lilshieste,yes ProductService uses those 4 dependencies.

Comment: In that case, you should have a single constructor that takes *all* of the dependencies. (Otherwise, you'll run into `NullReferenceException`s when you try to use the service.)

Comment: @Lilshieste,if i make single constructor then will it work :
container.RegisterType<IProductService, ProductService>(new InjectionConstructor(typeof(IUserDal<Users>), typeof(IItemDal<Item>), typeof(IRoleDal<Role>), typeof(IBranchDal<Branch>)));

Comment: I've never used Unity before (I've usually stuck with ["poor man's DI"](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/11/06/WhentouseaDIContainer/ "Mark Seemann - When to Use a DI Container")), but I don't believe that would work correctly. Instead, I think you would just do `container.RegisterType<IProductService, ProductService>();`, and the DI Container takes care of the rest. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1483686/926713

Comment: To clarify on my previous comment: I believe the code you posted under **Type 1** would be correct (even if `ProductService` has a constructor that takes multiple parameters).